# Problem with build SFML project with mingw

Tags: c++, build, g++, mingw, sfml

I want to build simple project:

```
////////////////////////////////////
// Headers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

#define SFML_DYNAMIC
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Entry point of application
///
/// \return Application exit code
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");

    // Start main loop
    bool Running = true;
    while (Running)
    {
        App.Display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I build it with: 
g++ main.cpp -I./include -L./lib -o main -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -static-libgcc .
Everything compile without erros, but when I run it looks:
[image]

I try to build with:
-lopengl32 -lglu3s
Without -static-libgcc and #SFML_DYNAMICS
A lot of combinations, but I get the same result: black command window instead of normal window with graphics.
I use SFML 1.6 , and gcc 4.5.2 ( I have the same problem on 3... version :/ )
Anyone know what I do wrong ? Or how to compile it ? I know i can try visual studio, but I want to make it with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this - I used MinGW under Windows XP, and I get a window pop up.  This looks normal to me.

Try some more examples from the tutorials.

Comment: This simple code http://pastebin.com/BiEs92Ri works good :/ But when I try to run example with window, it isn't appaer